# Using fragments as items in RecycleView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I googled this answer but didn't find something for me.

I want to use fragments (two different fragments) as items on RecycleView.

If you know how I can do it please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: why???? what is the purpose of recyclerView? You can create adapter with the view and in bind method to put new fragment there but WHY?

Comment: using fragments as items in RecycleView does not sound conceptually right. Fragments are entities with their own complex lifecycle and when used as items inside the RecyclerView, they will be very complex to manage. A more appropriate solution for your problem would be to use 2 different types of ViewHolders

Comment: You do not want to use fragments inside a recycler view .. Fragments have their own life cycle methods, and should not be considered to just be 'views' ...

Comment: @ViktorYakunin why? - скажу так: есть два фрагмента, показываются как два разных экрана. Нужно быстро сделать список-аккордеон в котором развернутый элемент списка - второй фрагмент, с его логикой и прочее. Просто верстку поменять чуть и все.

Comment: @ArtemShevchenko So your first fragment would be a list of items and the second would be details view, right? it is much easier to make custom fragment animation and to use fragment manager. There are a lot of ways to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an interface and use it as your generic type of your RecyclerView and Adapter. Your item's layout will be this interface. And finally your fragments implements this interface.

Note: Fragments may cause irregularity since they are attached activity. Not preferred!